# Logback XML to Groovy

Tags: xml, logback, logback-groovy

I have a Loback XML configuration file. I need to use Groovy for the same configuration. Being new to Groovy, I'm at loss. I tried the online translator at http://logback.qos.ch/translator/asGroovy.html but it didn't work. Maybe because the configuration contains SpringProfile and Janino conditional processing. The XML code is this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml" />
<springProfile name="dev,staging">
    <logger name="guru.springframework.controllers" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    </logger>>
</springProfile>
<springProfile name="production">
<logger name="guru.springframework.controllers" level="WARN" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</logger>
</springProfile>
<if condition='property("spring.profiles.active").contains("dev")'>
    <then>
        <logger name="guru.springframework.helpers" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
        </logger>
    </then>
    <else>
        <logger name="guru.springframework.helpers" level="WARN" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
        </logger>
    </else>
</if>
</configuration>
```

I would appreciate if somebody helps me with the same configuration in Groovy.

Comment: I wonder the same about how to convert the `springProfile` tag. Maybe simply use plain groovy checking for this functionality?

Comment: Your main problem would be the inclusion part as with logback groovy configuration including is not supported. If it is possible for you to also get the base.xml translated to groovy, you might try to work around the include statement. Look at the comments here: [link](http://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-1002)

Comment: Given https://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-1591, it would be nice with a tool that can convert the Groovy configuration to XML instead... but perhaps that's asking for too much. :-)